# Vaadin 8 Datefield

Tags: java-8, vaadin8

How can i hide the immediate validation for the datefield in Vaadin 8 . I have the follwing code

```
dateField.setLocale(new Locale("fr", "CA"));

binder.forField(dateField).withValidator(new Validator<LocalDate>() {
  @Override
  public ValidationResult apply(LocalDate value, ValueContext context) {
    if (LocalDate.now().equals(value)) {
      return ValidationResult.ok();
    } else {
      return ValidationResult.error("the date is not the current date");
    }
  }
}).withValidationStatusHandler(new BindingValidationStatusHandler() {
  @Override
  public void statusChange(BindingValidationStatus<?> statusChange) {
    if (statusChange.getResult().isPresent()) {
      ValidationResult validationResult = statusChange.getResult().get();
      if (validationResult.isError()) {
        label.setCaption("the date is not the current date");
      } else {
        label.setCaption("the date IS the current date");
      }
    }
  }
}).bind(CustomDate::getLocalDate, CustomDate::setLocalDate);
```

The result is however, that vaadin default validation (for example when the entered dateformat is not the expected format ) getting execued and my validation. I want to do the validation of the format expecitly in my validator. how to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: Not related to your question but I recommend using Java 8 lambdas instead of anonymous classes to improve readability a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `setComponentError` works for your use case. It should provide a way to override default error message.

For examples, see [Handling Errors](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/application/application-errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but you can check if it works as described in the documentation ([here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-datefield.html)):

```
DateField date = new DateField("My Date") {
    @Override
    protected Result<LocalDate> handleUnparsableDateString(
          String dateString) {
        try {
            // try to parse with alternative format
            LocalDate parsedAtServer = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
            return Result.ok(parsedAtServer);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
           return Result.error("Bad date");
        }
    }
};
```

According to documentation, client-side validation can be hidden via CSS.